# Why is the Fragment element in Android layout written with a lower case 'f'?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

All other elements start with an upper case letter, like RelativeLayout, TextView, etc.

Is there a particular reason why the Fragment element is always used as `<fragment ... />` instead of `<Fragment ... />`?

Comment: Not only `<fragment>`, but `<include>` and `<merge>` also written in lowercase since they are not `View`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fragments when defined in XML aren't actually views. The full view name is specified, or it assumes `android.view` for the package and finds the rest. But a fragment is only truly specified when it includes the `android:name` tag. It acts like a keyword, which are typically written in lower case. Thus, `Fragment` refers to the class, and `fragment` is the placeholder in XML for fragments.

As Andrew mentioned in the comments, any special item, such as `<include>` and `<merge>` are written in lower case, as they are not `android.view`'s.