# Error inflating layout - Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to create a fragment in main activity so later i can add elements dynamically in, when i run the app i get this  error:

```
04-29 19:32:47.318 E/   AndroidRuntime(27813): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Fragment
```

When i try to run the app without the `<Fragment>` tag in main.xml it works

MainActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<Fragment
    android:id="@+id/fL"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyFragment:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
 View root;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglayout, container, false);
    return root;
 }
}
```

fraglayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MyFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Also tried
class="com.mycompany.myapp.MyFragment"
instead of`android:name` in main layout`<fragment>`

Full logCat(E):

```
04-29 20:11:03.444 E/dalvikvm(4221): heapsize Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_nativeMinimumHeapSize 0
04-29 20:11:03.444 E/dalvikvm(4221): heapsize Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_nativeMinimumHeapSize 15154664
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221): Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 4221
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Fragment
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Fragment
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:296)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1941)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  ... 12 more
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mycompany.myapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-29 20:11:03.945 E/AndroidRuntime(4221):  ... 22 more
```

Comment: Can you please show the full logcat error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using lowercase "**f**" instead of uppercase letter "**F**" on `main.xml` layout while writing `Fragment`:

```
// <<<< start with lowercase
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/fL"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Some explanation about the solution I have found on another question:

> Fragments when defined in XML aren't actually views. The full view
>   name is specified, or it assumes  android.view for the package and
>   finds the rest. But a fragment is only truly specified when it
>   includes the android:name tag. It acts like a keyword, which are
>   typically written in lower case. Thus, Fragment refers to the class,
>   and fragment is the placeholder in XML for fragments.
>
> As Andrew mentioned in the comments, any special item, such as
>    and  are written in lower case, as they are not
>   android.view's.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21948080/3669559

Comment: LOL, it worked, can you explain it please? Shouldn't it be an uppercase `F`

Comment: @xYuri Check the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating 
    XML tags are case sensitive, uppercase usage of Fragment is invalid, that was the problem.

Comment: I know that why am asking shouldnt it be `Fragment` with an uppercase F as every other layout tag?

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake, i misread the docs on Android Devs. Its lowercase f, i was running into this error for 2 days now and tried lots of things to fix. Thanks again ^_^

Comment: @xYuri no problem, also found a good explanation for you and updated my answer.

Comment: Now it makes sense, and thats why i assumed its an uppercase F when i read it fast thinking its like any other view